# Determining whether x=1 is a regular singular point in the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider differential equation: $x^3(x^2-1)^2(x^2+1)y" + (x-1)xy' + y = 0$. Determine
whether $x=0$ is a regular singular point. Determine whether $x=1$ is a regular singular
point. Are there any regular singular points that are complex numbers? Justify
conclusions.

I guess I just don't know where to start with this problem. I can't find anything in my textbook about determining whether certain values of $x$ are regular singular points.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, rewrite the equation in standard form:

$$ y'' + P(x) y' + Q(x) y = 0$$

A point $x_0$ is a **singular point** if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ diverge as $x \rightarrow x_0$.

A singular point is **regular** if $(x - x_0) P(x)$ and $(x - x_0)^2 Q(x)$ do not diverge as $x \rightarrow x_0$.

So in your case,

$$ P(x) = \frac{ (x - 1) x}{x^3 (x^2 - 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)}, \quad Q(x) = \frac{1}{x^3 (x^2 - 1)^2 (x^2 + 1)}.$$

Note that these expressions can be simplified a little bit. Now you can check whether or not these expressions diverge or converge using the usual limit computations, which are made much nicer since these expressions are rational functions.

Comment: what about as x → 1? rather than x0

Comment: Isn't it the lim p(x) * x and the lim q(x)*x^2 ?

Comment: I have covered the method in generality. $x_0$ is the placeholder I'm using for whichever point you're trying to check.